# How to solve this "TypeError": None?

Tags: python

I would like to use [this program](https://github.com/HSASec/ProFuzz) to simulate ProfiNet protocol to send packets. This program is running well under Linux, but for some reason I want to let it running under windows, and when I try to let it run, I got this:

```
>>>python Fuzzer.py -w false -s 00:1E:37:3A:CC:50 -d 6c:ae:8b:29:6f:72 -t dcp -i eth0 -c 100


Profinet Fuzzer. Call it like
Fuzzer.py -w false  -s 00:19:99:9d:ed:ab -d 00:1b:1b:17:ba:8a -t pnio -i eth0 -c 10
or try Fuzzer.py -h for help.
Needs Administrator-Rights to send packages!


Fuzzing will start with following parameters:
Source:                 00:1E:37:3A:CC:50
Destination:            6c:ae:8b:29:6f:72
Frametype:              dcp
Number of packets:      100
Interface:              eth0
Sniffing:               false
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Fuzzer.py", line 144, in <module>
    fuzzer(packets, options.interface)
  File "Fuzzer.py", line 74, in fuzzer
    responses.append(srp(packet, timeout=1))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 357, in srp
    s = conf.L2socket(iface=iface, filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, type=type)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 240, in __in
it__
    self.ins = open_pcap(iface, 1600, 0, 100)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 347,
 in <lambda>
    pcapdnet.open_pcap = lambda iface,*args,**kargs: _orig_open_pcap(pcapname(if
ace),*args,**kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 171, in <lam
bda>
    open_pcap = lambda *args,**kargs: _PcapWrapper_pypcap(*args,**kargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 135, in __in
it__
    self.iface = create_string_buffer(device)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 69, in create_string_buffer
    raise TypeError(init)
TypeError: None
```

The OS is Windows 7 Ultimate and the Python version is 2.7.9, and the gcc compiler is use tdm-gcc.

Why I got this and how could I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it says `Needs Administrator-Rights to send packages!` at the top. my guess is you need to `run as admin`

Comment: Guessing from the traceback, it looks like `pcapname('eth0')` returns `None`. Perhaps you need to run as admin to get the pcap name for an interface?

Comment: I have run this program with administrator-rights but it still show this error. Maybe the function used to get pcapname under Linux and Windows is not the same?

Comment: `eth0` seems like the name of the interface under unix, not windows. I guess the name is different for windows systems?